# Raycast Engine: Rendering Solid Door

Tags: rendering, basic, raycasting

I am currently having an issue with a raycast engine that I am working on. I am currently adding non-teleporting doors to the rendering engine, but I am getting some strange artifacts. I have included some drawn examples of each case.

[image: raycast example 1: correct]

This is a vertical(north-south) door viewed from the -X angle(looking east). As you can see this is how the door should be drawn in all cases.

[image: raycast example 2: incorrect]

Here is the same door, but viewed straight on from the Y axis(looking south/north). As you can see this is when the visual artifacts begin to appear. that block that is drawn in the middle of the doorway comes from the right side and will move left until you get to the +X angle(looking west).

This behavior replicates itself in all both the horizontal and vertical open doorways. They appear normal from one angle, but then the strange artifact will move from right to left (or vise-versa on opposite side), until at some point an overflow error is thrown, because either the X-collision or Y-collision jumps to some absurdly high number

Here is the code that I use for determining Collisions. This is written in basic because I have not converted it to C/C++ yet. both functions are called with a GOTO statement and are able to return for the function they were called.

```
`X and Y are the non-precalculated ray coordinates while COLLX and COLLY are precalculated for the typical orthogonal cubes
`For when DX(direction X) is the greater magnitude (-1, +1). Called by @CASTXLOOP
@XDOOR
`ignore any occurences of T=2, for drawing code only
IF T==10 THEN @XDOORH `horizontal east-west door
T=2
IF COLLX-FLOOR(COLLX)>=.8 THEN RETURN `return positive collision to be drawn
IF SGN(DX)>1 THEN @CASTXLOOP `X-ray going the wrong direction to detect door

COLLY=Y+DY*(FLOOR(X)+.8-X) `Mulltiplied by fraction of X to +.8
COLLX=FLOOR(X)+.8
RETURN `Collision point returned
@XDOORH
T=2
IF COLLY-FLOOR(COLLY)>=.8 THEN RETURN `Return positive collision to be drawn
IF SGN(DY)>1 THEN @CASTXLOOP `Y ray going wrong direction
IF FLOOR(Y)+.8-Y>=DY THEN @CASTXLOOP `Distance to door collision is greater than magnitude 1

COLLX=X+DX*((FLOOR(Y)+.8-Y)/DY) `Important, move by magnitude of DY distance to .8
COLLY=FLOOR(Y)+.8
RETURN `Collision point returned

`For when DY(direction Y) is the greater magnitude (-1, +1). Called by @CASTYLOOP
@YDOOR
IF T==10 THEN @YDOORH
T=2
IF COLLX-FLOOR(COLLX)>=.8 THEN RETURN `Return positive collision to be drawn
IF SGN(DX)>1 THEN @CASTYLOOP `X ray going wrong direction
IF FLOOR(X)+.8-X>=DX THEN @CASTYLOOP `Distance to door collision greater than magnitude 1

COLLY=Y+DY*((FLOOR(X)+.8-X)/DX)
COLLX=FLOOR(X)+.8
RETURN `Collision point returned
@YDOORH
T=2
IF COLLY-FLOOR(COLLY)>=.8 THEN RETURN `Return collision to be drawn
IF SGN(DY)>1 THEN @CASTYLOOP `Y ray going wrong direction

COLLX=X+DX*(FLOOR(Y)+.8-Y)
COLLY=FLOOR(Y)+.8
RETURN `Collision point returned
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found what I was doing wrong. I was using the non-precalculated variables for my ray coordinates which gave incorrect results.